# Ajax send request per second and make high CPU usage

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, web, websocket

I have an application which sends request per second to view and there I get data from API and return response from client so

- Ajax(send request)->
- View(Send request)->
- Api(Return response for view)->
- View(Return response for client)

I saw that uses a lot of CPU.

1. Why is it usages a lot of CPU?
2. How can I optimization it? - I must press the point that I download currencies   and I need download data per second
3. Should I use WebSocket?

Ajax code:

```
 var ajaxFn = function () {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '{% url "coinbase_currency_ajax" %}',
                      success: function (response) {
                          if(response) {
                              for(var elem in response) {
                                  $("#"+elem).text(response[elem]+"$");
                              }
                              setTimeout(ajaxFn, 1000);
                          }
                      }
                  });
          };
          ajaxFn();
```

View code:

```
def currency_price_list(request):
   client=CoinbaseService().client
   btc = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair='BTC-USD') #API COINBASE
   ltc = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair='LTC-USD')
   eth = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair='ETH-USD')
   bch = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair='BCH-USD')

   return JsonResponse({
       "btc": btc['amount'],
       "ltc": ltc['amount'],
       "eth": eth['amount'],
       "bch": bch['amount']
   }, safe=False)
```

Comment: Show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network activity doesn't sound like something that should be taking CPU... You might want to check if the initial creation of each request, or your subsequent processing of the retrieved data is CPU-heavy.

If it is in fact the networking, then yes, maybe look into if the API supports Websockets.

Comment: How Can I check each request is CPU-heavy? Create loops and monitoring CPU?

Comment: You should profile your code using your favorite browser's devtools, to see what your code spends a lot of time on. Many tutorials are online.